# Jquery move menu element from one div to another

Tags: jquery, html

I need to move elements from one div to another on window resizing. My code works fine moving element from left to right div, but I am not able to make it work to move element back from right to left div.
Thanks

**Markup:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-10" id="left_bar">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">All (181)</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Special Editions (5)</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Delivery (12)</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Free delivery (4)</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Italian (100)</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Friend of Feudo (83)</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pizza (6)</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2" id="right_bar">
      <div class="dropdown col-12">
        <button type="button"
           id="dropdownMenuButton"
           class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"
           data-toggle="dropdown"
           aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Other
          </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Associated JavaScript:**

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var left_bar = $('#left_bar').width();
    var right_bar = $('#right_bar').width();
    //$('#dim').html('left: '+left_bar+' - right:'+right_bar);
    var left_ele_dim = 0;
    $('#left_bar ul li').each(function(){
            left_ele_dim += $(this).width();
        if(left_ele_dim > left_bar){                    
            $(this).remove().appendTo($('.dropdown-menu'));
        }else{
            $(this).remove().appendTo($('.nav'));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The html or even a snippet would really help understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here is what I have.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  var left_bar = $('#left_bar').width();
  var right_bar = $('#right_bar').width();
  var left_ele_dim = 0;
  var move = false;
  var first = $("#right_bar li").first()[0];
  $('#left_bar li').each(function() {
    if(left_ele_dim + $(this).width() > left_bar) {
      move = true;
    }
    var width = $(this).width();
    if (move) {
      if (first != undefined) {
        $(this).remove().insertBefore($(first));
      } else {
        $(this).remove().appendTo($('.dropdown-menu'));
      }
      $(this).data("width", width);
    } else {
      left_ele_dim += width;
    }
  });
  move = true;
  $('#right_bar li').each(function() {
    if(left_ele_dim + $(this).data("width") > left_bar) {
      move = false;
    }
    if (move) {
      $(this).remove().appendTo($('.nav'));
      left_ele_dim += $("#left_bar li").last().width();
    }
  });
});
```

First of all. That didn't work because you looped only through items in `#left_bar`. Second. You can't just use `width()` to put element back from dropdown. When it is inside dropdown, it is not displayed, so `width()` will return 0. Also, you put `li` items inside dropdown, where there is no `ul`. I didn't fix it here, but for you that might be a problem in future.

Now here is how it works:

`var move = false;` determines whether to move all the rest items or not. For some reason you may have a situation when some items (not just one) should be moved at a time and I think you'd like to safe the order of them. `first` is to store current first item of dropdown if it exists. Also a trick to save the order of items when restoring them.

Inside first loop you check all items in `.nav`. If some of items overflows width, you want to move it and all items after it. So you set `move = true`. Before moving you save current width of it.

If `first` element exists, this means some items were moved to dropdown previously, so they have "greater index", you want them to be restored later. This is kind of stack. So you insert new item before. Otherwise, you simply append new items to dropdown.

Then you set `data("width")` for further usage.

Only if you didn't move the item you add its width to total width.

In the second loop you check items from dropdown. The idea of `move` here is opposite. If you can't move this item back to nav, than you can't move all next also. You check it by reading `data("width")`. If you move item back to nav, you use `$("#left_bar li").last().width()` to add actual width, which in fact can be different from saved.

This algorithm may have some troubles if the window is resized with large steps, but on manual resize it works fine.